# Using localStorage as a nested dictionary

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, nested, local-storage

I have seen the current solutions on stackoverflow such as:

```
Storage.prototype.setObject = function(key, value) {
    this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
}

Storage.prototype.getObject = function(key) {
    var value = this.getItem(key);
    return value && JSON.parse(value);
}
```

But I am trying to do something like:
localStorage[a][b] = 5 with a function call localStorage.setItem('a', 'b', 5).

I currently have a code that is not working because of referencing problems:

```
Storage.prototype.setVal = function(key, val) {
    var val = Array.prototype.pop.call(arguments);
    var cur_depth = this;
    for (var i in arguments) {
        var cur_key = arguments[i];
        cur_depth = JSON.parse(cur_depth[cur_key]);
    }
    cur_depth = JSON.stringify(val);
}
```

And my last, even more hacky, attempt:

```
Storage.prototype.setVal = function(key, val) {
    var val = JSON.stringify(Array.prototype.pop.call(arguments));
    var keys = ''; // hacky eval solution
    for (var i in arguments) {
        var cur_key = arguments[i];
        keys += '["' + cur_key + '"]';
    }
    eval('this' + keys + '=' + val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit theoretical (as in, off the top of my head) but I would do something like:

`Storage.prototype.setVal = function () {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var key = args.shift();
  var val = args.pop();
  var curr, obj;
  curr = obj = this.getObject(key);
  while (args.length > 0) {
    curr = curr[args.shift()];
  }
  curr = val;
  this.setObject(key, JSON.stringify(obj));
}`

If you could do a plunkr with your code though it would be better as i prefer to verify what I'm writing.

Answer (score 0):

Something around these lines could work. It can be simplified a bit if you would use single storage pair for the whole dictionary (now handling of the first key requires additional attention).

```
Storage.prototype.setVal = function () {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

  var storageKey = args.shift();
  var value = args.pop();

  var storageValue = this.getItem(storageKey);

  if (args.length === 0) {
    storageValue = value;
  } else {
    if (!storageValue) {
        storageValue = {};
    } else {
      if (typeof storageValue !== 'object') {
        storageValue = {};
      }
    }

    recursiveSet(storageValue, args, value);
  }

  this.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify(storageValue));
};

function recursiveSet(object, keys, value) {
  for (var i in keys) {
    if (i == keys.length - 1) {
      object[keys[i]] = value;
    } else {
      if (!object[keys[i]] || typeof object[keys[i]] !== 'object') {
        object[keys[i]] = {};
      }
    }
    object = object[keys[i]];
  }
}
```

Here is [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/btl6Up4fXEjCK97r6SWp).